# how use service with angularjs 1.5

Tags: angularjs

in angular2 a service is a class that I inject in my component.

in angularjs should I create a file javascript that contain a class as a service and then I export it ??
after that I inject it in my controller to have access to my functions ??

for example this is my LoginComponent

```
let LoginComponent = {
  restrict : 'E',
  template,
  controller
};
export default LoginComponent;
```

I need to add service as I'm adding controller ?
or the service is injected one time by application
if some one can provide me an example
**thank you**

I found this it is correct ?

```
class MyService {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'My Service Name'
    this.purpose = 'For demo only'
  }
  sayHello(name) {
    return 'Hello, ' + this.name
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .service('MyService', MyService)
```

add user by module and inject it in every controller I need it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the correct way of doing it.

```
class MyService {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'My Service Name'
    this.purpose = 'For demo only'
  }
  sayHello(name) {
    return 'Hello, ' + this.name
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
       .service('MyService', MyService);
```

Now you can write your service logic like this:

```
function MyService() {
   this.myService= function(broadcast) {
     //code here
   };
```